format each date in an array of dates
I have the following array of dates. How can I format each date in this array to 'mm/dd/yyyy'?
I am attempting something like this which isn't formatting correctly.
const formattedDates = this.displayEffectiveDate.map(date => new Date(date));
[ "2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00" ]


You're mapping to a new Date, not formatting the Date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript

[ 2024-02-29T00:00:00, 2024-03-31T00:00:00 ] is not valid JSON or JavaScript. "isn't formatting correctly" isn't really telling us what is happening, please be as detailed in the question as you can.

Check out toLocaleString with locale "us-en".

This could be just string manipulation. Is [ "2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00" ].map(s => s.replace(/(....)-(..)-(..).*/, "$2/$3/$1")); doing what you need?

It seems to me that this is just a matter of string manipulation for which you don't need to create Date objects:


const dates = [ "2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00" ];
const result = dates.map(s => s.replace(/(....)-(..)-(..).*/, "$2/$3/$1"));

console.log(result);




Try this


let array = [ '2024-02-29T00:00:00', '2024-03-31T00:00:00' ]

for(let i = 0; i<array.length; i++){

     const a = array[i].split('-', 3)

     const day = a[2].split('T', 1)[0]
     const month =  a[1]
     const year = a[0]

     const mmddyyyy = `${month}-${day}-${year}`

     array[i] = mmddyyyy

}

console.log(array)




If your displayEffectiveDate looks like this:
this.displayEffectiveDate = ["2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00"];
You could create a new Date object from the ISO 8601 date string.
d.getMonth() + 1 to get the month
d.getDate() for the day
d.getFullYear() for the year
String(...).padStart(2, '0') to ensure the month and day are always two digits
It should look like this:
this.displayEffectiveDate = ["2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00"];

const formattedDates = this.displayEffectiveDate.map(date => {
  const d = new Date(date);
  const month = String(d.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // Months are 0-indexed, so we add 1
  const day = String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  const year = d.getFullYear();
  return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
});

The result would be [ '02/29/2024', '03/31/2024' ]

You can use toLocaleDateString() to get the output for your advantage.
Refer the code below:


const displayEffectiveDate = [ "2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00" ];

const formattedDates = displayEffectiveDate.map(date => {
    const formattedDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        year: 'numeric'
    });
    return formattedDate;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(formattedDates));




Ah, an answer actually formatting dates instead of manipulating strings. Note the comment on reusing a format object here if performance is relevant.

You can use the Date object, then use method for this like this:


function dateToMDY(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1; //Month from 0 to 11
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '/' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + "/" + y;
}

var dates = [ "2024-02-29T00:00:00", "2024-03-31T00:00:00" ];
console.log(dates.map(d => dateToMDY(new Date(d))));



